# Query from relational tables with conditions using Entity Framework c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I'm having trouble query from relational tables using **Entity Framework**

Here are my tables
[image: MyTables]

**The Connection between tables are: `visitId in SurgeryDate refers to Visit Table & patientId in Visit Refers to Patient Table`**

I want to select All records from `SurgeryDate whare date="SomeDate"` **including**  `ONLY Last visit From Visit` **including** patient info `From Patient` and store it in `List<SurgeryDate> aList`
So I can navigate through every item of the list to get any information form the three related tables

I tried the following

`surgList = db.SurgeryDates.Where(d => d.date == surgeryDateCbx.DateTime.Date).Include(d => d.Visit ).Include(p=>p.Visit.Patient).ToList();`

but it fetch surgeryDate with related visit but it fetch only the first visit while I need the last visit (Max id)
I have tried many ways but always ending with error. I know it is my lack, so I'm asking your help

Answer (score 1):

First, relations in your diagram is not quite right. There Patient is the table having primary key (id) for relations to SurgeryDate and also to Visit (patientId). In EF with correct relations in the db, navigational properties get generated so that you don't need to build any 'join'. Your EF Linq query would look like:

```
// likely to be selected from a datepicker
// as a sample say next day's list
var date = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);  
ver surgeryListForDate = ctx.SurgeryDate
                         .Where(sd => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(sd.Date) == date)
                         .Select(sd => new {
           Date = sd.Date,
           PatientId = sd.PatientId,
           FullName = sd.Patient.FullName,
           LastVisit = sd.Patient.Visits.OrderDescendingBy(v => v.Date).FirstOrDefault)
});
```

Comment: Thank you. The patientId in the SurgeryDate is not connected, only integer number stored

Comment: LastVisit = sd.Patient.Visits.OrderDescendingBy(v => v.Date).FirstOrDefault), This will not work i need to go through SurgeryDate>Visit>patient . I tried to manipulate the code but still not working

Comment: They aren't connected but you can still try to do "inner select" in the lambda query if needed, since you have all the require information on the `sd` to accomplish that

Comment: surgList = db.SurgeryDates.Where(d => d.date == surgeryDateCbx.DateTime.Date).Include(d => d.Visit ).Include(p=>p.Visit.Patient).ToList();  this is working but it fetch only the first visit . I need the last visit

Comment: "visitId in SurgeryDate refers to Visit Table". You are using that navigation pattern, which is wrong for your purposes. Check the query, it uses navigation over sd.Patient. Just follow that.